# Бесконечный ли это цикл?

Tags: циклы

```
;
Сейчас_время:=GET_UTC_TIME();

if (Сейчас_время>in1) then
     in2:=1;
else in2:=0;

end_if;
```

Условие:
Допустим 'Сейчас_время=8:01', а 'in1=8:00', тогда 'in2:=1'.

Вопрос:
Когда произойдет выполнение else 'in2:=0', другими словами, когда перестанет действовать условие?

Заранее благодарю всех.

Это не прикол. Я думаю что это бесконечный цикл, и для его завершения нужно добавить еще одно условие.
Недавно начал изучать программирование, прошу снисхождения в ответах.

Comment: я конечно не специалист, но по-моему это вообще не цикл а просто условная конструкция

Comment: Не бесконечный, потому что здесь нет никакого цикла.

Comment: Хорошо, извиняюсь.
По существу вопроса ответите?
Вопрос: Когда произойдет выполнение else 'in2:=0', другими словами, когда перестанет действовать условие?

Comment: На этот вопрос невозможно ответить, потому что неизвестны типы переменных `Сейчас_время` и `in1` и неизвестен принцип работы функции `GET_UTC_TIME`.

Comment: GET_UTC_TIME - выдает настоящее время в каждый момент времени.
Сейчас_время и in1 - тип time(внутренний тип среды разработки скада системы).

Comment: На вопрос ответить по-прежнему невозможно, так как неизвестна реализация этих самых внутренних типов. В частности, неизвестно, реализован ли у типа time вообще оператор >, а если всё-таки реализован, то неизвестно, каким именно образом.

Comment: Ветвь else выполнится если Сейчас_время<=in1. Например 7:59<8:00

Comment: @becouse но это не точно, так как оператор > может оказаться реализован так, что всегда возвращает истину

Comment: @andreymal тогда это не оператор сравнения. Вопрос "когда" ответ "когда условие ложно". Если вы написали оператор ">" некорректно, то ситуация "условие ложно" не наступит.